# Using git how to transfer code from one branch to another existing branch (not necessarily master)?

Tags: git-bash, git

I have my code in one branch in the team git repo.
Now I need to "transfer" (i.e push) it into another branch of the same repo which team members are using. How can I do that ?

I prefer using git bash.

P.S - The new branch I have to transfer to is not *"master"*.

Comment: You should really look at some of the free training material out there.  http://try.github.io/ is a good one to start with.  http://gitimmersion.com/ is good too.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

go to the target branch (`git checkout target`) and merge the code-having branch (`git merge code-having`). then, if needed, push the updated target branch to its remote.